# Calculating molal depression constant from latent heat of fusion

Tags: physical-chemistry

> Calculate molal depression constant of water if latent heat of fusion of ice at $0^\circ \text C$ is $80 \text{ cal/g}$.

All I could find was the equation $K_f=\frac{0.002T^2}{L_f(\text{in cal/g})}$ at http://www.sciencehq.com/chemistry/depression-of-freezing-point.html

**How was this equation derived?**

Comment: Any physical chemistry textbook will have this derivation. In my copy of Moore's Physical Chemistry (http://www.amazon.co.uk/Physical-Chemistry-W-J-Moore/dp/0582442346/ref=sr_1_4 - apparently now out of print) it's on pages 247-249.

Comment: Could you tell me what that equation is actually called?

Answer (score 1):

[image][image]

I've uploaded the derivation. I'm using Cengage Physical Chemistry. This book is recommended by my highschool teacher.